# how to pass multiple parameters in twig template ? - php symfony mvc

Tags: symfony, twig

i want to know how to pass more than one / multiple parametre from twig template to controller.

I can pass one parameter  from twig to my controller file.

```
<a href="{{ app.service.urlAlias('administration/events', 'edit', event.ID) }}" class="button hollow">Edit</a>
```

In the above code `administration/events` is the controller path and `edit` is the function and i am passing only one parameter which is `event.ID`

How do i pass more parameter `event.active` and `event.check` from the same url?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `Symfony`? I've never seen `app.service.urlAlias` being used to generate a link

Comment: yes I am using Symfony.

Comment: Just asking because `app.service` is not a default member of [`app`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#the-app-global-variable). Not sure why you aren't using [`path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#linking-to-pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you pass the parameters in twig template as object like this

```
<a href="{{ path('path-name-defined-in-controller', {
    id: event.id,
    next: whatever.string
}) }}" class="button hollow">Edit</a>
```